# button in c# not firing

Tags: c#, button

I am writing a simple code it has 3 buttons 2 that will need to open up other forms and one to close the program. When i start the program the exit button will not work even though i have it coded the same as any other time i have wrote a program.

When i press any of the buttons nothing happens. Im not 100% sure how to use the buttons to open another form but i know the exit button should work as is.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _3343_ParksJ_Lab02
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void workerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WorkerForm workersForum = new WorkerForm();
        }

        private void suppervisorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SupervisorForm workersForum = new SupervisorForm();
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly will i be looking for to see if they are wired together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe your buttons' click events to the event methods before they'll fire correctly.

You can check the `Designer.cs` file to see if this has already been done, though I'm guessing it hasn't. You'll be looking for something like this:

```
this.workerButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.workerButton_Click);
```

One way to do so is directly in the constructor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    workerButton.Click += workerButton_Click;
    suppervisorButton.Click += suppervisorButton_Click;
    exitButton.Click += exitButton_Click;
}
```

Normally, I'd do this through the designer. Select each Button in turn, then open the properties panel and double-click on the event you wish to subscribe to, which will create the corresponding event method in the code-behind for you.

[image]

Comment: The designer does that in the InitializeComponent() method

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea if that were the case in this example, then the exit button would close the form, which OP said is not working.

Comment: Most likely he has an issue with subscribing to the given events. But instead of bodging it around, he should check that the designer is properly set up and does its job right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at .Designer.cs file and make sure your button is adding the correct delegate method.  In your case it should exitButton_Click.

Sometimes when you change names of a button VS designer does not make the name change correctly in the .Designer file.  Very rare but it happens.

Comment: Ok i know what you are talking about. i figured it out by just double clicking on the button in the designer i forgot this is the best way to get the code in the .cs and not to just type it all in.